# Is it possible for each agent creates tables unique to each of them?

Tags: netlogo

Suppose I have 2 agents and I want to make tables for them use `table` extension. Instead of one table to store their values, I want to ask each agent to create, say, `table_0` for the first agent (which has `0` for the `who` variable, hence the name), and `table_1` for the other one, so the first agent won't bother the second agent's table and vice versa.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what turtle attributes are for. You don't need to have different names for each table, a turtle keeps track of its own copy of any attribute. So just have something like:

```
turtles-own
[ my-table
]
```